# Static method create an instance of itself

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a static method that basically creates an instance of the class that made the call automatically.

In this example, I would like class `A` to create an instance of itself. How can this be done? The below code gives an error when executed.

```js
class Model {
  static find(someVar) {
    let inst = new this.constructor[this.constructor.name]()
    // Do some extra stuff with the instance
    return inst
  }
}

class A extends Model { }

A.find()
```

Comment: `let inst = new this();` should work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/fu3jar8h/

Comment: @ChrisG WOW didn't think it would be that easy...

Answer (score 2):

Every static method of a class has `this` context which points to the class after dot

```js
class Model {
  static find(...args) {
    console.log("My name is", this.name) // <- this will print "My name is AModel"
    return new this(...args)
  }
}

class AModel extends Model { }

AModel.find(); // <- passing `this` context to be the AModel class.
```